# CSS - Aligning Navigation bar with images and text

Tags: html, css, menu, navigationbar

I have a menu (shown in the picture below) which I am trying to correctly align the text with the images (i.e. [img] [text]) as well as "stretch" the whole contents to fit all the width.

Image:
[image: Navigation Menu]

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
      <ul>                                        
           <li><a class="current" href="home.html" title="">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="services.html" title="">TRANSPORT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">ACCOMODATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">DEALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" title="">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu{
    width:900px;
    height: 50px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #f7951e;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

}
#menu ul{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
#menu ul li{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    line-height:42px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#menu ul li a{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float:next;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a.current{
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu ul li:nth-of-type(1){

    background:url(./images/iconza/house_32x32.png) no-repeat;
    float: start;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#menu ul li:nth-of-type(2){

    background:url(./images/iconza/Car.png) no-repeat;
    float: start;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

#menu ul li:nth-of-type(3){

    background:url(./images/iconza/house.png) no-repeat;
    float: start;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#menu ul li:nth-of-type(4){

    background:url(./images/iconza/offer.png) no-repeat;
    float: start;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#menu ul li:nth-of-type(5){

    background:url(./images/iconza/mail_32x32.png) no-repeat;
    float: start;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is already an answer around here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+align+image+text
;-)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use `display: table-cell;` in `#menu ul li` instead of `float: left;` (I've learned it from a book about responsive design), and put background-images into html as imgs:

see my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k8gjx/)**

Here is the amended html:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>                                        
    <li><a class="current" href="home.html" title=""><img src=""><span>HOME</span></a</li>
    <li><a href="services.html" title=""><img src=""><span>TRANSPORT</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""><img src=""><span>ACCOMODATION</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""><img src=""><span>DEALS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" title=""><img src=""><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#menu{
    width:900px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f7951e;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;

}
#menu ul{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    display:table-row;

}
#menu ul li{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    list-style:none;
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu ul li a{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}

#menu ul li span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#menu ul li img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #ababab;
}
#menu ul li a.current{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#menu ul li:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Another suggestion here would be to have all the images in a sprite, and put them into the menu as background images (this is assuming  you don't need to have the actual image elements for accessibility). But this solutions is pretty much on point and is a great CSS solution that has support down to IE8. Other than that, for the nice vertical aligning and full width features in your image, you'd need JS to support. But simple is always better.